# Change opacity of region defined by ParametricRegion

Tags: regions, style

I can not find in the documentation how to set `Opacity` of region defined by `ParametricRegion`.

```
Region@ParametricRegion[{x, y, z}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]
```

---

[image]

Comment: You can wrap `Style` around `ParametricRegion[…]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Region[Style[
  ParametricRegion[{x, y, z}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
  Opacity[.2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ParametricRegion[{x, y, z}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}], 
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[.2]]`

Answer (score 4):

Here as a short answer: You can wrap `Style[…]` around the region definition like so

```
Region[ 
    Style[
        ParametricRegion[{x, y, z}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}],
        Opacity[0.5, Red]
    ]
]
```

[image: Styled Region]